# How to test facebook "like" button?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Working on integrating the "like" button into a site.
The site is currently running on XAMPP in localhost mode.  Not visible anywhere outside this computer.

Upon the site user clicking the button I need to log the event into the database.  I have their information from a form they filled-out prior to even seeing the button.

Here's my problem.  I am trying to debug the code that does a lot of this.  However, if I click on the "like" button just one time it is forever grayed-out after that.

I can clear cookies on Firefox and get the button back.  This also means that I have to login to FB again.  This makes for a very difficult debugging session.  Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here's my problem. I am trying to debug the code that does a lot of this. However, if I click on the "like" button just one time it is forever grayed-out after that.

If you hover over the greyed-out version, you should see an X to remove your like.

Comment: Ah, so simple.  I was hovering over the word "like" and saw nothing.  You have to hover over the checkmark.  Thanks!

Comment: I like having "unlike", which was more intuitive.